# Digital is to digitise, as analogue is to ..?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If I'm converting something from analogue to digital, I **digitise** it.

What am I doing if I convert from digital to analogue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51880/discussion-on-question-by-matt-potts-digital-is-to-digitise-as-analogue-is-to).

Comment: I wonder why this is considered off-topic? Some of the ensuing conversation about signal processing is off-topic, but that's been moved to chat anyway.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You ***reconstruct***, as in a [reconstruction filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_filter) found in digital-to-analog converters:

> a reconstruction filter is used to construct a smooth analog signal from a digital input

Comment: You aren't reconstructing, you're estimating, unless you have sufficient conditions—like a finite amount of bandwidth captured—which is probably impossible in real life.

Comment: Quite possible for many important use cases e.g. human threshold of hearing.  See [Nyquist theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

Comment: @DanielvanFlymen: Even then if the samples are digital they're necessarily quantized.

Comment: Reconstruction can be an estimate. Like medical CT/PET and MRI where it's always called reconstruction and it's always been an estimate from the very beginning. Digitizing involves three processes: sampling (from signal to samples), quantizing (from samples to numbers), then encoding (from numbers to digits). Then D to A needs to reverse all three. Reconstruction is a good summary of the whole process.

Comment: reconstruction seems to be the way to go. See this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter

Comment: @FlorianCastellane Or better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_reconstruction ... this is most certainly the right answer.

Comment: Reconstruct makes sense, but it has the same issue as the other answers, it doesn't *specifically* mean changing digital to analog. You could reconstruct incomplete digital data by interpolation or manual editing, and the result would be digital data, not analog.

Comment: @barbecue Fair point. Then the term is "signal reconstruction" or "analogue reconstruction".

Comment: @SusanW I think the key point is, if you want to specifically indicate you're converting TO an analog format, you have to put the word analog in there. Anything else is ambiguous. \

Answer (score 22):

This is an interesting question.

The distinction between the two is characterised by the distinction between the discrete and the continuous. To take something discrete and make it continuous, one *interpolates*.

[Dictonary.com defines interpolate as](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20interpolate):

> Mathematics. to insert, estimate, or find an intermediate term in (a sequence).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51909/discussion-on-answer-by-nwr-digital-is-to-digitise-as-analogue-is-to).

Answer (score 12):

I know of no such specific antonym to digitizing; however, by digitizing an analog signal, we are actually encoding it. And, so when we convert the digital signal back to analog for consumption, we are actually ***decoding*** it.

ODO:

> **[decode](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decode)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1.2** Convert (audio or video signals) into a different or usable form, for example to analogue from digital in sound reproduction

Comment: Again, being somewhat technical, sampling (which is really the process of digitizing) doesn't _necessarily_ involve encoding.

Comment: as a signals processing major, I strongly disagree with this answer.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane yep, I strongly disagree too. It's like muddling "translating" and "comprehending": you might have to decode the digital encoding, but that's not the bit that necessarily involves anything to do with analogue reconstruction.

Comment: Encoding does not necessarily imply encryption.  Converting an analog signal into digital (numbers) is an encoding process.  Think of a measuring cup, when you fill it to one of the lines, you have encoded that volume as a number (of units).  Sampling is also a form of encoding, turning signals into numbers.  Decoding is a valid term for converting the numbers (of units) back into analog.

Comment: @BrentWashburne: Encoding is rather close to being the opposite of encryption - it's formatting your data according to an a convention that facilitates (rather than hinders) comprehension of it.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps the simplest solution here is to use the prefix "un-":

- **un-digitise**
- **undigitise**
- (or their "z" equivalents)

Some might argue that a hyphenated word is not a single word, and some might suggest that the above is not a "real word"; however the verb "digitise" itself is a relatively new addition, and we all know that language evolves through the addition of new words just like this.

In fact, "undigitise" (or "undigitize") is beginning to gain some traction, although so far it tends to be used to refer to reducing one's reliance on technology rather than converting something from digital to analogue.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the only real antonym...

Answer (score 8):

In a context where digitize means "quantize and record digital samples of a continuous-valued signal", the verb for going the other direction is to *reproduce* the signal from the samples. I wouldn't say it fills in the blank in the subject-line of your question, but it's often the word that fits in actual usage.

Comment: But *reproduce* is ambiguous because you can reproduce digitally by file copying, or you can reproduce in analogue by printing or playing the digital sound recording.

Comment: @Chris: That's part of what I mean by it not fitting the fill-in-the-blank. It needs context. FWIW I generally wouldn't use *reproduce* for making an exact copy of a digital file except perhaps in the case of data protected by an *error correcting code* where I was missing part of the original and used the code to recreate the missing bits (thereby *reproducing* the file).

Answer (score 8):

I believe the word you are looking for is "render". It has a variety of applications mostly having to do with converting something into something else or with the creation of art or graphic design either in physical or virtual form.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter what the analogue source is (sound, image or text) when using the word *[digitise](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/digitise)* (British English) or *[digitize](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/digitize)* (American English) however going the other way (from digital to analogue), the words used would depend on the resulting analogue output.

For images, text, or 3D object, it would be ***[print](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/print)***

For audio it would be ***[sound](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sound)***

> verb (used without object)
>
> 13. to make or emit a sound.
> 14. to give forth a sound as a call or summons:
>       *The bugle sounded as the troops advanced.*
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 20. to cause to make or emit a sound: to sound a bell.
> 21. to give forth (a sound):
>       *The oboe sounded an A.*

Comment: Re sound, hearing depends on an analog process, so anything that plays a digital file so you can hear it is automatically converting it to analog.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/368573/59244) (*undigitise*), I'd use

> *de-digitise* or it's z-equivalent, *de-digitize*

Examples of similar constructions are *compress* / *decompress* and *escalate* / *de-escalate*.

Answer (score 2):

Digital is to digitise, as analogue is to [smooth](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothCurve.html) - to transform or modify (a graph, distribution, or function) so as to make it smooth; to lessen irregularities or fluctuations in (something that can be represented by a graph)(OED).

The OP asks

*What am I doing when I convert something from digital to analogue*? (i.e. when I produce continuously variable physical quantities (OED) from a series of discrete measurements).

'***Smoothing***', by some form of interpolation, describes in lay terms 'what I am doing' - making continuously variable physical quantities from a series of discrete measurments.

Comment: I believe what you have is the opposite of "discretize" or "quantize", not "digitize"?

Comment: @Mehrdad - aren't "digitize" and "quantize" synonyms?  Digitize -> render as numeric values (with clear implication of a limited range of possible numbers); quantize -> convert into a limited set of possible values.  I can't see any clear distinction between the two.

Comment: @Mehrdad - please can you clarify the distinctions you are making between discretise, quantise and digitise.

Comment: There are *lots* of reasons why these aren't the same, some more technical than others. But to give you an idea without worrying about being 100% technically accurate: imagine a hot sheet of metal whose temperature you're trying to measure. First you might "discretize" the sheet by chopping it up into little pieces. Then you might "quantize" each piece's temperature by touching your old-fashioned alcohol-based thermometer to it and marking the closest square on the graph paper beside it. Finally you might "digitize" your results by expressing them as numbers. All these steps are independent.

Comment: ...Important takeaways: (1) discretization does not necessarily even involve values or numbers... you can discretize anything, even your sandwich, (2) quantization is arguably about *approximation* and therefore involves numeric values, but doesn't concern itself with how those values are *represented* (the grid lines you marked on paper are not themselves numbers/digital; they're merely quantizations of what you measured), and (3) digitization doesn't necessarily even involve approximation (`y = x * x` is a 5-character digital description of a smooth curve). @PeriataBreatta

Comment: All of *my* old-fashioned thermometers are *mercury*-based, and my gerontologist - no, I mean my cardiologist - still measures my blood pressure in millimeters of a column of mercury as well. We used to play with mercury a lot as kids, breaking it into tiny balls and then pushing them all back together with our fingers. These days, if you broke a mercury thermometer on your hardwood floors, the EPA would send out a Haz-Mat team! Playing with mercury in the palm of your hand was educational and fun and it didn't hurt us at all. Have you seen my keys anywhere? I thought I left them in my jeans.

Comment: Dan: definitely!
@MarkHubbard: Funny, I actually wrote mercury initially and then spent some 10 seconds deciding if I should change it to alcohol... which I ended up doing because I want that technology to die already. =P One spill is all it takes...

Answer (score 2):

To critique your question, I don't think "digitize" is an acceptable verb since it's ambiguous and non-technical. The word *discretize* would be more apt, since what you're actually describing is an arbitrary function or process which takes values from the *discrete* to the *continuous*. And to perform that process, we estimate a continuous range of values between two *known* discrete points.

In short, the word you're looking for is **interpolate**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation):

> In the mathematical field of numerical analysis, interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points.

Comment: Not sure about this at all. Interpolation doesn't imply _converting to analogue_: it's just a necessary step towards analogue reconstruction. I could just be re-sampling to change the data rate.

Comment: "Digitize" is absolutely an acceptable verb. You read too much into the OP's question by assuming that he isn't looking for a technical term, and you also consider this a technical term even though it is one which is used by non-technical people for non-technical reasons.

Comment: Rather than assuming the OP is or is not looking for a technical term, let's ask him

Comment: @SusanW You're right, interpolation doesn't necessarily imply *conversion to analogue* but *conversion to analogue* definitely implies interpolation.

Comment: @Beanluc "Digitize" is pretty broad, and so I felt that "discretize" is more precise and technical since the OP is asking for clarification of a process. But I'm happy to amend my answer if they reply here.

Answer (score 2):

Analogize. You are making an "analog" of the original source by way of a digital sampling.

Comment: + 1. It follows the standard pattern (seen in *humanize*, *vaporize* etc.). Of course another meaning has preempted the word. But there is no reason the word shouldn't have a second meaning. It might come to if digital-to-analogue conversion became as commonplace as analogies. / Most of the other answers are *describing* what happens when you analogize (in our new sense), not *naming* the process.

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about moving from one storage\playback protocol\format to another.

e.g Convert a `.mp3` music file (compressed, lossy) to `.wav` (bitmap, uncompressed, lossless)

In that case you would say you were `re-encoding` or `converting` it to another format\protocol.

VLC, for example, uses the term `convert`.

Answer (score 0):

**"Convert".**

An analog-to-digital converter digitizes, but what a digital-to-analog converter does is, it converts.

This is assuming that what you want to capture in your analog medium is something which is already in digital format. If it's not, then what you want to do is to simply "record" it.

Answer (score 0):

When I take a digital video or sound source and convert it to analog (for example by using a tape recorder to record an MP3) I am making an **[analog recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_recording)** of the digital source.

In earlier decades, recording a sound almost always meant making an analog recording by magnetic tape. For example, I might record a meeting with a tape recorder, or have a tape recording of a phone message on my answering machine.

When digital recording started to become affordable and mainstream, the word *digital* was added to indicate that digital techniques were being used instead of the default analog (and of course for marketing reasons.)

"Hey check out my new digital voice recorder, I can record a whole day of classes without having to change a tape!"

Fast forward to today, and digital recording is standard, while analog is the unusual special case. Today, recording is assumed to be digital, unless you specify otherwise by saying it's an analog recording.

Answer (score 0):

In most everyday situations it depends on the medium.

My photo camera collects light and *digitizes* the amount at each pixel to obtain a picture file. To go back to analog I **display** the picture. My video camera does something similar, but I **play back** the video. The sound wave *digitized* to an audio file (whether compressed or not, lossy or lossless doesn't matter) gets **played back**, too. The sheet of paper *digitized* by your fax machine gets **printed** by my fax machine. The geographic position *digitized* by my GPS device can be **marked** on a map, or perhaps I want to **visualize** a whole track. The position of my stylus on my digitizer board (or your touch device) tends to stay digital, although it might well be used to manipulate things that find their way back into the analog world.

But even for these media, the words above are not truly the opposite of *digitize*. For each of them, a more common term would be the more obvious counterpart. You **take** a picture, **record** a video or audio, **scan** a sheet of paper, and perhaps **log** GPS positions. So if people use *digitize* instead of these, they do so for a reason. Here are some reasons I can imagine:

1. to encompass different media.

   In this case I think **render** or **reproduce** would be most fitting. Both of these terms can mean other things, so they will require context or explanation.
2. to sound technically up to date.

   In this case you have to make a decision. You can either use one of the terms I just suggested, without additional context, and hope people will understand what you mean. You can provide more context, thus making your statement longer. Or you can use the more established everiday terms, and risk sounding <strike>understandable</strike> boring.
3. to focus on the specific properties of a digitizing operation.

   Here the mathematical aspects mentioned in other answers come into play. Perhaps you are worried about the loss of detail due to the digitization process, and want to counter that using interpolation? But then your real problem is more specifically with discretization (usually in the domain, e.g. finitely many distinct pixels) and quantization (usually in the range, e.g. finitely many different color values). So again it's not an exact pair of antonyms.
4. to describe something without physical representation.

   I believe there are people who would use the term *digitize* when ripping an already digital DVD to a file on their computer. In that case, “digital” is (imprecisely) used to mean something without physical manifestation. You don't have a disc any more, and your computer looks the same as it did before you got the file. In this situation, a proper opposite would focus on the material aspects of the analog representation. You might call your printout (of a scanned sheet or a picture you took) a **hardcopy**, but I can't think of a verb for this.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be

> analog (analogue)

modeled after *catalog* (*catalogue*) and *log*, each a verb.

I also like the answer *analogize* given by DoritoStyle (modeled on *humanize* etc.).

The virtue of these possibilities is that they fit an established pattern.

A drawback may be that they already have established usages.

Of course my answer proposes a usage rather than identify one.

Some of the other answers seem to describe what happens in a digital-to-analog conversion rather than *name* the process.

Comment: "*Some of the other answers seem to describe what happens in a digital-to-analog conversion rather than name the process.*" That is because the process has no name other than ***digital-to-analog conversion*** - which is already [well established](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).